# xslt 2.0 checking if element is referenced in a number of other elements in the same folder

Tags: xslt, dita

I have some DITA content here.

A dita map looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN"
 "../dtd/technicalContent/dtd/map.dtd">
<map id="e7de5b">
    <title/>
    <topicmeta>
        <othermeta name="title" content="File Loader Guide for SAP HANA"/>
        <othermeta name="status" content="Authoring:closed"/>
    </topicmeta>
    <topicref href="9df1475208c.xml"/>
    <mapref href="ec152470.ditamap"/>
</map>
```

In this folder, I know that this is the main map because it references the only other DITA map (`<mapref href="ec152470.ditamap"/>`). Bascially, the main map of a folder is the map not referenced by any other map in that same folder (there can be any number of maps).

I have a file that contains a list of all maps, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<maps> 
<map path="Path\ToTheMap" name="e7de5b.ditamap" /> 
<map path="Path\ToTheMap" name="ec152470.ditamap" /> 
</maps>
```

What's the best way to check if a map is the main map in the folder, i. e. to check if it is referenced by any other map in that same folder?

So far I've got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fo fn xs">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <docMaps>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </docMaps>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="maps">

    <xsl:for-each-group select="map" group-by="@path">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(current-group()) = 1">
                <mapdoc path="{current-grouping-key()}" name="{@name}"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- check -->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there's only one map in the folder, it's trivial. But in the other case... I tried for-each loops but I cant figure it out.

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> the main map of a folder is the map not referenced by any other map in that same folder (there can be any number of maps).

That sounds to me like

```
select="maps/map[not(doc(@path)/map/mapref/@href = $name)]/@name"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll work than into my code in the next days and see if it did the trick.